# foundation tabs with one up not working

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I have two tabs on my page and I would like the page to init with both tabs closed.  I cannot get it to work.  If I switch to accordion I can get both to init closed.

Is there a different property for tabs?

Also I would assume closing a tab would occur if you click on a tab that is already open. However that is not the case.

```
<div class="section-container auto tabs" data-section data-options="one_up: false;">
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/omuvik/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was a design decision on the part of the Foundation team, as tabbed content normally has one section open at all times. If you resize a browser window with all accordion elements closed to the breakpoint where those become tabs, the first one will be forced open, which makes it seem like a deliberate behavior.

You can try setting a callback function in your data-options attribute: if you remove the "active" class from all tab sections, they'll all be closed.